# The Picture's Position is Not Where I Want It

Tags: graphics, formatting

This code,

```
\setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headheight}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headsep}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\textwidth{-2in}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight}
\addtolength\textheight{-2in}
\usepackage{layout}
```

is not interfering with my image's location. It appears above the question instead of below it.

Here's the code where I add it,

```
\item Americans can be quite suspicious, especially when it comes to government conspiracies. On the question of whether the U.S. Air Force has withheld proof of the existence of intelligent life on other planets, the proportions of Americans with varying opinions are given in the table.\par
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{question13}
    %\caption{ShareLaTeX logo}
    \label{fig:question13}
\end{figure}
```

I've done this in another document except with the first snippet of code. [image: This is what happens]

Comment: the _only_ reason to use a `figure` environment is to specify the content may be floated (moved) by latex to avoid bad spaces at page breaks.So it is not clear what the problem is, and as you have not provided any code that people can run it isn't possible to debug the float placement in your case. Can you not just use `tabular`, why `figure` and `\includegraphics` here?

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[H]` (requires `\usepackage{float}`).

Comment: @HenriMenke even with `[H]` the formatting will be normalized and not set as part of the list. Simply removing the figure environment would be much better,.

Comment: I know the `figure` appears above question **2.13**, but does it *float* to the top of the *page*? We may need additional context in order to address the problem.

Comment: It floats above the question. I haven't added more text to test if it's to the top of the page. I moved it down to the next question and it formatted properly but it won't for 2.13.

Comment: @Peekoh you have used `[htp]` so explictly specifying that the figure may be placed at the top of the page so moving to the top of the page _is_ being formatted properly.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want a float so use

```
\item Americans can be quite suspicious, especially when it comes to government
 conspiracies. On the question of whether the U.S. Air Force has withheld proof
of the existence of intelligent life on other planets, the proportions of Americans
with varying opinions are given in the table.
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{question13}
\end{center}
```

although if that table is a representation of the image it would be just as easy, and produce more consistent formatting  to use a `tabular` rather than `\includegraphics` and set the table with LaTeX.

Comment: I used your solution and it fixed it perfectly. I guess I don't understand how to use figure enough. The first block of code would mess it up but I don't know why. This will have to suffice.

Comment: @Peekoh the _only_ reason to use `figure` is to specify that latex can move that content and insert it later to help with page breaking, so not using figure is what you should do here. the first block of code isn't really related other than it changes the page size so changes page breaking decisions and so figure placement. It is a rather strange page setup specified but that is unrelated to this issue.